# Row standardize a Sparse Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have the following sparse matrix;-

```
library(Matrix)
 a <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5),
                   j = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 5), x = 1)
```

I want to divide the rows by their row sums so that this matrix becomes the following sparse matrix:-

```
b <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5),
                  j = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 5),
                  x = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 0.5, 0.5))
```

How can I row standardize a sparse matrix in R

Comment: `a/rowSums(a)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide `a` by rowwise sum.

```
b <- a/rowSums(a)
b
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                            
#[1,] 0.5 0.50 .    .    .   
#[2,] .   0.50 0.50 .    .   
#[3,] .   0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
#[4,] .   .    1.00 .    .   
#[5,] 0.5 .    .    .    0.50
```